# SQL Antipattern name?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, lookup, anti-patterns

I am looking for the name, if there is one, for a bad practice concerning a FK referencing a look-up table.

I googled and also checked in a book (SQL Antipatterns) that I have but did not find anything about it.

We have a case where a table (A) has a non-nullable column with a FK referencing a look-up table (B).

In that look-up table, we have a special row where ID = -1 and DESCRIPTION = Unknown.

It was done that way instead of simply making the column in (A) nullable and then deal with the null appropriately.

I would like to know if this pattern has a name ?

Comment: I don't consider this an "antipattern".  This structure is often used in dimensional data models to ensure that `join`s succeed.

Comment: This is "using a special value". From a general software viewpoint NULL is a "special value" of the de facto type of a nullable SQL column. But for your SQL idiom "special value" is reasonably used for non-normal non-NULL values. But it's not necessarily an anti-pattern. Other terms you will see are "sentinel value" (but that's used generally in software re ending algorithm branches), "magic value" (but that's used generally in software for literals that should be names), "default value" (but that's typically treated as normal once in a program/DB state, SQL included) or "dummy value".

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know if this pattern has a name ?

It's typtically called the "Unknown Member", and it's definitely not an anti-pattern in dimensional modeling, and OLAP in general.  See eg: https://www.kimballgroup.com/2003/02/design-tip-43-dealing-with-nulls-in-the-dimensional-model/

In reporting, it's important to get the same result from a

```
FACT LEFT JOIN DIMENSION
as
FACT INNER JOIN DIMENSION
```

As many reporting workflows start with the user selecting dimension members to filter the facts.  So you really need a row in each dimension table to not miss rows in some query patterns.

In OLTP I agree it's generally better practice to use a nullable Foreign Key than to introduce an Unknown Member, but some business domains it might be common parlance to introduce something that looks like an Unknown Member.